# unable to boot windows or ubuntu and Maind Partition became unallocated after changing boot partition's file system

Tags: boot, dual-boot, boot-repair, grubrescue, grub-efi

```
boot-repair-4ppa200                                              [20220324_2347]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos6)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.04
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 44096 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg /ldlinux.sys


================================ 0 OS detected =================================


================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, focal, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: A04(0.4) from Dell Inc.
This live-session is in Legacy/BIOS/CSM mode (not in EFI mode).



============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________


Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________


Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________


Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________


fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 298.9 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Disk identifier: 0xd065a941
      Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
sda1  *         2048    206847    204800   100M ee GPT
sda2          206848 243161576 242954729 115.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda3       420341760 625139711 204797952  97.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda4       243163134 420341759 177178626  84.5G  5 Extended
sda5       243163136 244211711   1048576   512M  b W95 FAT32
sda6       244213760 420341759 176128000    84G 83 Linux
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sdb: 28.84 GiB, 30943995904 bytes, 60437492 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x00057670
      Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sdb1  *     2048 60437491 60435444 28.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:320GB:scsi:512:4096:unknown:ATA ST320LT020-9YG14:;
sdb:30.9GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Kingston DataTraveler 3.0:;
1:1049kB:30.9GB:30.9GB:ntfs::boot;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                
sdb                                                                                                                
└─sdb1 ntfs     5030364A30363776                     00057670-01                          Ubuntu 20_04_4 LTS amd64 

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                        Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1               25.6G  11% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sdb1              fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096

====================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings

========================= sdb1/syslinux.cfg (filtered) =========================

DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/

==================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================

Unknown BootLoader on sda1


Unknown BootLoader on sda2


Unknown BootLoader on sda3


Unknown BootLoader on sda4


Unknown BootLoader on sda5


Unknown BootLoader on sda6





Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Just pasting the text from boot repair is not enough. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1399139/edit) and include the following information. 1. Which version of Ubuntu are you using? 2. What exact commands 9or GUI method) did you use to "**chang boot partition's file system**"? 3. Why on earth did you do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)